# Prevent object from being garbage collected for life of JVM

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, permgen, metaspace

I have a **ton** of pooled objects that will be constantly reused during life of JVM. These objects should **never** be garbage collected.

I would like a way to optimize the JVM to never attempt (and waste time) checking eligibility for garbage collection. This is especially important since the volume of the pooled objects is going to be quite high, and can cause CPU and GC pressure.

Over a period of time these numerous objects will get into JVM old-gen, and then metaspace, and I would like for a way to hint/optimize the JVM that checking GC eligibility for these numerous objects even during Full-GC (causing longer jvm pauses) is a waste of time, and to never attempt them.

What is the right way to optimize for this situation?

One option is to use off-heap memory. Can I retain these objects in the JVM heap to avoid the off-heap complexity but still optimize GC?

Comment: As long as you have strong reference an object it should never be eligible for gc. Are your pooled objects being referenced by weak or strong references?

Comment: It would indeed have strong reference, but intent here is to not spend ANY CPU cycles trying to check for GC eligibility for a class of objects, especially during stop-the-world GC pauses.

Comment: “*Over a period of time these numerous objects will get into JVM old-gen, and then metaspace*”—no, they don’t. People should stop thinking that “Metaspace” was another name for “PermGen”. The Metaspace doesn’t contain Java objects. Regarding your question, the simplest solution is to avoid full GCs.